# Searching through a linked list.

Tags: c, pointers, search, linked-list, malloc

So i've been trying to understand the difference between a regularly defined structure without using malloc linked list that does utilize malloc.

The issue that i'm having right now is trying to search through the structure (pi) to find each part number that has a cost greater than what was entered into the search. this is my entire program so far. I've added comments for each section.

I'm simply not sure how i am suppose to search through each structure to compare its price to the search price.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Item {
int quantity;
float cost;
char partNum[10];
struct Item *next;
};

void printItem(struct Item* pi);
void enterItem(struct Item* pi);

char search [100];

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
struct Item *pi;
struct Item *head;
int done = 0;
int i,j;
char choice;

//    ENTERING ITEM INTO THE STRUCTURE 
head = NULL;
while (!done) {
    printf("Enter another item? (y/n)");
    choice = getchar();
    if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') {
        pi = (struct Item *)malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
        enterItem(pi);
        pi->next = head;
        head = pi;
    } else {
        done = 1;
    }
}
//    SEARCHING FOR ITEM BY PRICE
printf("Enter a price to find all items more expensive, or type 'exit':");
while (strcmp(search, "exit") !=0) {
    gets(search);
    for (j = 0; j<i ; i++) {
        if (strcmp(pi[j].cost, search) ==0) {
            printItem(pi);
            pi = pi->next;
        }
    }
}


}
getchar();
getchar();
}
// FUNCTION FOR PRINTING STRUCTURE ITEM
void printItem(struct Item* pi) {
printf("Quantity: %d\n", pi->quantity);
printf("Cost: $%.2f\n", pi->cost);
printf("Part # %s\n", pi->partNum);
printf("\n\n");
}

// FUNCITON FOR ENTERING IN NEW ITEM
void enterItem(struct Item* pi) {
printf("Quantity? ");
scanf("%d", &pi->quantity);
printf("Cost? ");
scanf("%f", &pi->cost);
getchar();   //need to clear out the carriage return from typeing in the cost
printf("Part Number? ");
gets(pi->partNum);
}
```

Comment: `for (j = 0; j<i ; i++)` is an odd for loop, especially considering that `i` has never been initialized.

Comment: ya I added that part in from another peice of code I had to search through a structure, but not a linked list. so I copied it over hoping I could modify it to work...didn't get far. @ooga

Comment: this line: for (j = 0; j<i ; i++) { is not correct, it should be: for (j = 0; j<i ; j++) { n

Comment: this line:  pi = pi->next; needs to be moved to after closing brace of the if code block so it causes pi to always be stepped to the next entry in the linked list

Comment: the code creates a circular linked list, so how does the 'for' loop know when to stop searching?  Since the variable 'i' is not set to the number of entries in the linked list, when the search stops depends entirely on the (random) value in the uninitialized variable 'i'

Comment: A much better way to create a linked list is to append to the list, rather than insert at the beginning of the list, with the next field of the latest new node on the list being set to NULL.  Then a search through the list can recognize the NULL in the next field and stop searching.  This has the side effect that the 'i' variable can be completely eliminated from the code.

Comment: as the code is currently written, the 'j' variable is never incremented and the 'i' variable is always incremented, so the second parameter of the for statement will never fail until 'i' rolls over from +2gig to -2gig

Comment: because 'j' is never incremented and is initialized to 0, this line: if (strcmp(pi[j].cost, search) ==0) { will always look at the first entry in the linked list.  However, pi[j] is treating pi as an array of pointers, so the line should be if (strcmp(pi->cost, atof(search) ) ==0) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were doing wrong is comparing string(`search` variable) with a float(`cost` variable) using `strcmp`. This won't give you the desired output.

Instead, lets use `-1` to indicate the `exit`, since parsing string and converting it to float is off-topic. Start iterating from `head` up to finding `NULL`, and compare the prices of the each item.

```
float price;
struct Item *it = head;
printf("Enter a price to find all items more expensive, or type '-1' to exit:");
scanf("%f", price);

// check price for the 'exit' -- compare with -1

while (it != NULL) {
    if (it->cost > price)
            printItem(pi);

    it = it->next;
}
```

Comment: so is there any way i can use strcmp in order to search for the price? this does work though so thank you. @qamyoncu